# How setup a Node.js development environment using Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I want create a complete Node.js environment for develop any kind of application (script, api service, website ecc.) also using different services (es. Mysql, Redis, MongoDB). I want use Docker to do it in order to have a portable and multi OS environment.

I've created a `Dockerfile` for the container in which is installed Node.js:

```
FROM node:8-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` file where adding the services that I need to use:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  mysql:
    ...
  redis:
    ...
networks:
  webnet:
```

I would like ask you what are the best patterns to achieve these goals:

- Having all the work directory shared across the host and docker container in order to edit the files and see the changes from both sides.
- Having the `node_modules` directory visible on both the host and the docker container in order to be debuggable also from an IDE in the host.
- Since I want a development environment suitable for every project, I would have a container where, once it started, I can login into using a command like `docker-compose exec app bash`. So I'm trying find another way to keep the container alive instead of running a Node.js server or using the trick of `CMD ['tail', '-f', '/d/null']`

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having all the work directory shared across the host and docker container in order to edit the files and see the changes from both sides.

- use -v volume option to share the host volume inside the docker container

Having the node_modules directory visible on both the host and the docker container in order to be debuggable also from an IDE in the host.

- same as above

Since I want a development environment suitable for every project, I would have a container where, once it started, I can login into using a command like docker-compose exec app bash. So I'm trying find another way to keep the container alive instead of running a Node.js server or using the trick of CMD ['tail', '-f', '/d/null']

- docker-compose.yml define these for interactive mode

  stdin_open: true
    tty: true

Then run the container with the command docker exec -it

Comment: I use `docker-compose up` to start all services. When and where have I use the `-v` option? Furthermore, using `stdin_open: true tty: true` in the `docker-compose.yml` I'm not able to login in the container using `docker exec -it <container-name>` and the console returns this error `Error response from daemon: Container 447b0f43ghy42e8fc7bb87ed846cfd532978b2e9c6d56851e7b536f07a278a16 is not running`

Comment: volumes:
    - ./ghost/config.js:/var/lib/ghost/config.js

Comment: Volume example : volumes:
    - ./ghost/config.js:/var/lib/ghost/config.js  Ref : https://www.linux.com/learn/docker-volumes-and-networks-compose   . Do docker logs / docker inspect to check the problem.

Comment: One more recommendation, you need to copy package.json and do the npm install . Because it creates a layer and ignores if their is any future changes it will get ignored and start serving from cached layer. Ref 1 : https://forums.docker.com/t/making-volumes-with-docker-compose/45657/7 Ref 2: here a full example https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-compose-for-nodejs-development/

Comment: In the `Dockerfile` file I've removed the command RUN and CMD and in the `docker-compose,yml` file I've removed `/app/node_modules` volume and added fields `stdin_open: true, tty: true, command: /bin/bash`. Now, after running `docker-compose up -d` I'm able to login into the bash of container using `docker-compose exec app bash`. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Thats great to hear, if you want to share the folders between docker container and host you can do it using volumes . Follow this link   https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-compose-for-nodejs-development  . Note : volumes: – This section will mount paths between the host and the container.
.:/usr/app/ – This will mount the root directory to our working directory in the container.
/usr/app/node_modules – This will mount the node_modules directory to the host machine using the buildtime directory.